# How to convert Boolean predicates to numeric expressions

Tags: boolean-computation

I'd like to use Boolean expressions as numeric values, as in:

```
a = 3 < 2
b = 3
a * b
```

but the final result of that is 3 False, instead of 0.  I can do something like:

```
a = 3 < 2
b = 3
a * b /. False -> 0 /. True -> 1
```

but that seems awkward.  I suppose I can make a function to do these replacements, but is there a more natural or a builtin way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps, `a  =  Boole[3  <  2]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: What m_goldberg says. Your double replacement is longer than necessary BTW, and could have been written as `a * b /. {False -> 0 ,True -> 1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating [the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100079/how-to-convert-boolean-predicates-to-numeric-expressions/100113?noredirect=1#comment271649_100079):

```
a = Boole[3 < 2]
b = 3
a * b
(* -> 0 *)
```

Comment: Usually. when giving an answer that merely restates what was posted by someone else in a comment, one makes it a community wiki and gives attribution where applicable.